# How to save the generated image from Django ImageKit to ImageField?

Tags: django, image, django-models, imagefield, django-imagekit

I generate the image using the code below:

```
source_file = open('/path/to/myimage.jpg', 'rb')
image_generator = Thumbnail(source=source_file)
result = image_generator.generate()
```

What is the proper method to save the generated "result" back to django ImageField? ie in a model
The generated result seems to be a _io.BytesIO object. And it seems I cannot directly save it to ImageField.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can use `PIL.Image` for this. `img = Image.open(result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `SampleModel` as below,

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

then,[`ContentFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class) do the magic for you. Follow the snippet,

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

source_file = open('/path/to/myimage.jpg', 'rb')
image_generator = Thumbnail(source=source_file)
result = image_generator.generate()
# additional snippet
django_file = ContentFile(result.getvalue())
sample = SampleModel.objects.create()
sample.image.save('sample_name.jpg', django_file)
sample.save()
```